# Addition of Non-const methods result in Seg Fault

Tags: c++17

I am observing undefined behavior/seg fault when I add the method `setValue` to `ClazzI` below.  Removing this method eliminates the issue; however, I have not been able to reproduce in a simple example.  The below roughly outlines what is being done and it seems the real issue relates to touching the member vector in the non const function.

```cpp
class AnotherClazz;

using AnotherClazzPtr = std::shared_ptr<AnotherClazz>;

class AnotherClazz {
public:
    AnotherClazz(const std::vector<double>& values)
        :m_values(values)
    {}

    std::vector<double> m_values;
};

class ClazzI;

using ClazzPtr = std::shared_ptr<ClazzI>;

class ClazzI {
  public:
    virtual void setValue(size_t i, double value) = 0;

    virtual ClazzPtr clone() const = 0;

    virtual ~ClazzI() = default;
};

class Clazz : public ClazzI {
  public:
    Clazz(const std::vector<double>& values)
        :m_values(values)
        , m_another(std::make_shared<AnotherClazz>(m_values))
    {}

    void setValue(size_t i, double value) override {
        m_values.at(i) = value;
        m_another = std::make_shared<AnotherClazz>(m_values);
    }

    ClazzPtr clone() const override {
        return std::make_shared<Clazz>(m_values);
    }
private:
    std::vector<double> m_values;
    AnotherClazzPtr m_another;
};
```

Calling clone whilst the `setValue` function seems to trigger a destructor call which then leads to the below.

```
Segmentation fault (Invalid permissions for mapped object [0x55a3b0309540])

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Comment: Code doesn't crash if it's not run. Methods don't get run just by being added. You forgot to post any of the code that actually *uses* this class, and hence, your question is incomplete and off-topic. When editing it to fix this, also consider first using a debugger and figuring out where it segfaults, after calling which functions, with which parameters and other variables. You might answer your own question in the process, and save yourself and readers time.

Comment: "I have not been able to reproduce in a simple example. The below roughly outlines what is being done..." We cannot really do anything without code that reproduces your problem. Even if we find an issue in the code you've posted, we cannot be sure it's the real problem. No solution to your question exists as-is

Comment: I'll try to reproduce in a simpler structure; however, I was primarily interested to know if there was any behavior introduced purely by defining a non-const function which might explain the issue.  The non-const `setValue` method's existence seems to cause the issue despite the fact it is never called in my code.

Comment: @mcguip likely you have undefined behavior somewhere that only manifests as a segfault when the function is added

Comment: @AndyG This is certainly helpful in itself.  Is there anything you could suggest that might have such a correlation?  The point at which the undefined behavior occurs is merely a call to the constructor with member variables which seems to in turn trigger a call to the destructor of the object itself.

Comment: @mcguip: Most common cause of undefined behavior is stepping out of bounds in an array (e.g. `vector[0]` on an empty vector). Compile with debugging symbols on and you may get more information from the runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've identified what the problem was, though it was entirely unrelated to the source and was related to bad symbols that got generated in my build output.